# how to order of has_many through by a specific field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, has-many-through

I have 3 models: `member`, `team`, and `team_enrollment`.  The structure is as follows:

```
class Member < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :team_enrollments    
  has_many :teams, -> {order 'team_enrollments.termination_date DESC NULLS LAST'}, through: :team_enrollments
end

class TeamEnrollment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :team
  belongs_to :member
end

class Team < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :team_enrollments
    has_many :members, through: :team_enrollments
end
```

I am trying to make it so that when someone calls a team from a member(so `Member.first.teams`), the teams are ordered in descending order by the attribute `termination_date` which exists on the `team_enrollments` table.  I also want it so that if `termination_date` is nil that it is at the end of the order.  I thought that the `has_many :teams, -> {order 'team_enrollments.termination_date DESC NULLS LAST'}, through: :team_enrollments` line above would work but it does not.  It seems to have no affect on the order.  how do I change this?

By the way, i am using postgres locally and in production.

Comment: That should work, looks like a bug. I've tried similar code and activerecord applies the ordering to the query retrieving the association. What rails version are you using?

Comment: Im using Rails 5

Comment: I see. What's on `ApplicationRecord`? Try to isolate the bug from the context. Your setup may have something to do with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would try using `default_scope` instead of trying to put the order clause in the association

```
class Member < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :team_enrollments    
  has_many :teams, through: :team_enrollments
end

class TeamEnrollment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :team
  belongs_to :member
  default_scope {order 'termination_date DESC NULLS LAST'}
end

class Team < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :team_enrollments
   has_many :members, through: :team_enrollments
end
```